# Automation of two related datasets using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I cannot share details or data for this question as it is for a client.

Here is a simplified version of what I am working with. I am working with a dataset that was generated by the client to be a network design for telecommunications. One feature class represents spans which are the aerial pathway between poles or underground pathway between pedestals. The other feature class represents the actual telecom cables that are to be placed that follow the pathways found in the spans table. These cables have different types, can continue across multiple spans, and more than one can be placed in a single span. In between each span is a point called pits with its own feature class, however that tables has nothing more then a Pit_ID. I don't think that this table or information will be useful for what I am looking to do, but maybe it will be.

See the example tables below:

Spans Table

[image: Spans Table]

Cable Table

[image: Cable Table]

Now what I am trying to do is fill out the fields (that will have to be added) to the Spans Table that are highlighted. There number of cables in a span don't have a predetermined limit and I have seen 10+ near the site of the cable feed source in a single span, hence the "etc." Because these cables are not directly buried but will be placed in conduits, the number of cables and types/sizes are relevant to know to determine the number of conduits needed. It is also relevant for aerial spans as only so many are allowed in a aerial span (at least without a more specialized engineering and permit.)

There maybe more than one direction this can go to arrive at the needed solution. One is more of a spatial solution since all of the cable lines overlap the span lines and share line segments. A simple Spatial join will not work since it is not a one-to-one situation. So I think that leaves some type of select by location but would have to be automated some how since each feature would have to be selected individually and then ran through the process to relate it to the other feature class. I am currently incapable of sorting this process out in an automated fashion. There maybe some other spatial route that could be done as well.

The other direction would be using just the information in the tables and I figure would be the more likely solution to be used. I don't see how a simple table join could be preformed to come to the solution either. This probably just leaves some python script to churn through the data using the two tables to fill in the needed information. With my current python skills, this too is also beyond me at the moment. I do alright using basic python in the field calculator, checking against multiple other fields in the row for a variable output using if/else and other python functions. When it comes to running arcpy functions, I am inexperienced and but looking at other examples, I can usually follow.

An added bonus for any direction would be to automatically add fields for the Cable[n]_ID and Cable[n]_type if there isn't enough blank fields for the number of cables in the individual span. I can get around this Manually adding a fields by large enough amount that I should have a few extra in the expect highest cable count in a single span.

I am also willing to export the tables to excel, working the process and then rejoining the finished excel product back with the feature class.

Given that I will have to go through this process many a times with new data-sets, I really need a semi/automatic approach to this.

Comment: There is a solution but it will require python.. and a lot of time! Using an update cursor with a where clause to limit the rows being updated is one way. Because you're trying to relate two fields a simple join will not suffice. However if you were to add a field to both tables and concatenate start and end pit (also potentially end pit and start pit) you can use a simple join and calculate with a python script - just be sure to include the existing Span field to append to or you will be overwriting existing spans. There's no way to avoid doing some python on this one.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. I don't quite understand how concatenating the pits will help me out in this process. My start and end pits of the spans do not line up with the cables. Since the cables go through many spans, the spans in the middle of a cable won't have anything to join with in regards to all of the cables that do not start or end with in a single span.

Comment: Ah, that's a totally different problem. Is there only one possible solution for start pit to end pit? Many years ago I worked on a telecommunications project that had a similar model, cable through conduit, but because there was more than one possible route from start to finish the process was entirely manual.